# How to connect and execute a SQL file non interactively using psql?

Tags: windows, postgresql, psql

I am trying to run the following command using psql but the --file argument is ignored event tough I manage to connect to the database.

```
psql "postgresql://postgres:admin12345@localhost:5432/Phoenix" -f "tables/book.sql"
```

The output on the terminal is as the screenshot shows.

[image: Command output]

What am I missing here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It might just be your font, but the `-f` doesn't look like a proper f

Comment: Heed the warning and look at "Notes for Windows Users" here [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html).

Comment: @Bergi you're right,  it's just the font lol.

Comment: What kind of terminal is that?

Comment: @Bergi it's a console emulator called Cmder.  You can find it here https://cmder.net/ .

Answer (score 2):

After googling and wasting hours on testing different SO answers, this worked for me:

```
psql -f "tables/book.sql" "postgresql://postgres:admin12345@localhost:5432/Phoenix"
```

It looks like the psql command requires that the command-line arguments appear before the connection string. That's a bit weird but it worked for me.

Also the quotes are optional. This also works:

```
psql -f tables/book.sql postgresql://postgres:admin12345@localhost:5432/Phoenix
```

I tried changing code page as indicated on the section "Notes for Windows Users" in the psql doc [psql docmentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html). The result is the warning does not show anymore but the command line args are still ignored if the connection string precedes them like as shown in the following logs:

```
C:\Users\Zack
λ cmd.exe /c chcp 1252

Active code page: 1252

C:\Users\Zack
λ psql postgresql://postgres:admin12345@localhost:5432/Phoenix -f "tables/book.sql"

psql: warning: extra command-line argument "tables/book.sql" ignored
psql (13.2)
Type "help" for help.

Phoenix=#
```

Theo only fix that works for me now is making the other args preced the connection string.

If someone knows more about why command-line args should precede the connection string, please provide more details.

Comment: They don't have to precede the connection string. `psql "postgresql://postgres:@localhost:5432/test" -f "test_sql.sql" ` and `psql -d test -U postgres -f "test_sql.sql"` work just fine for  me on Linux.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I'm not on Linux machine. It didn't not work for me on Windows.

Comment: I know. Read the section  "Notes for Windows Users" in the link I posted in my earlier comment.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I tried those instruction and I still get the same behavior. I updated my answer to give more details.